# How to check whether secure boot is enabled using python in windows os

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, bios

I basically want to check whether secure boot is enabled using a python script. Based on my research this data is apparently not exposed to the operating system. However games like valorant are able to check this data. So is there any way to programmatically check this data

Couldn't find any way to do it

Comment: Hi, This question is already answered here : https://www.hindicodingcommunity.com/2023/02/how-to-check-whether-secure-boot-is.html